# Converse of the Sobolev Theorem (Exercise 33. from Folland)

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Question 33. from Folland's book is the following:

(Converse of the Sobolev Theorem) If $H_{s}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C_{0}^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $s>k+\frac{1}{2} n$. (Use the closed graph theorem to show that the inclusion map $H_{s} \rightarrow C_{0}^{k}$ is continuous and hence that $\partial^{\alpha} \delta \in\left(H_{s}\right)^{*}$ for $|\alpha| \leq k$.)

To use the closed graph theorem, we need to know how to compare convergence in $ C_{0}^{k}$ and $H_{s}$. This is the first key point that I don't see. Moreover, I don't know how to proof the other facts too. I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: The first part boils down to: $f_i \to g$ in $H_s$, $f_i \to h$ in $C_0^k$ imply $g=h$. Can you elaborate on your difficulties here?

Comment: The norm in $H_s$ is given by $\|g\|^2_{(s)}= \int\limits(1+|\xi|^2)^s |\hat{g}(\xi)|^2d \xi $ and then norm in $C^k_0$ is given by $ \|h\|_{C^k_0}= \sum\limits_{| \alpha | \leq k}   \|\partial^{\alpha} h \|_u$. So, to obtain g = h I need to compare these norms, right? In the sense that some of these convergences implies the other

Comment: Ah, I had other definitions in mind. So the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$? All this information would be useful as a part of the question.

Comment: There's no need to show that one implies the other, at least at this point. Instead, it's enough that both convergences imply convergence in $L^2(B_R)$ (where $B_R$ stands for any ball).

Comment: Yes, it's in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I will complete the question above. I understand your point,  maybe a third mode of convergence solve the question. Thank you!